# Simulate slow network connection to MySQl server

Tags: networking, mysql, traffic-shaping, slow-connection

I tried [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)  and [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to simulate slow network connections.

I could slow down the network with fiddler but it is for Http and https protocols. With wireshark I was able to capture TCP & MySQL protocols but could not find a way to slow it down. Probably, am I missing something?

Is there any tool that can help in simulating a very slow network response times with MySQL?

P.S: I am on windows.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  *Why* do you want a slow network connection?  And are you talking about latency or throughput?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a quick and functional network condition simulator by installing [m0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall) on a computer with two network cards.  This computer then acts as a router.  m0n0wall has a traffic shaping feature which allows you to limit bandwidth in both directions, add latency and drop packets for any computer on the inside of the m0n0wall's network - this is enough for basic simulation of different network conditions, and it will not cost a great deal.